# inter process communication

Tags: linux, node.js, ipc

There's a process and a lot of child processes (Node.js)

which method is preferable to use for real-time communication between processes within a single machine: Linux IPC or TCP / UDP?

What are the limitations of the IPC?

Suitable whether IPC to transfer large amounts of information with minimum delay?

Comment: What's the order of magnitude of the throughput / latency  target?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, TCP/IP (even on localhost) is significantly slower than Linux pipes or socketpairs, so you should avoid TCP/IP (and probably even UDP/IP) if speed is a major concern.